# Can you treat a string as one object in a list in MATLAB?

Tags: string, list, matlab

I would like to make a list of strings in MATLAB using the example below:

```
x = ['fun', 'today', 'sunny']
```

I want to be able to call `x(1)` and have it return `'fun'`, but instead I keep getting `'f'`.

Also, is there a way to add a string to a list without getting the list giving back a number where the string should be? I have tried using `str2double` and a few other things. It seems like both of these thing should be possible to do in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to store a list of strings that have different lengths is to use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html). For example:

```
>> x = {'fun', 'today', 'sunny'};  %# Create a cell array of strings
>> x{1}                            %# Get the string from the first cell

ans =

fun
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a kludgy workaround, but 
    x = strsplit('fun.today.sunny', ',') 
produces a list with individual, callable strings.